# MSYS SDL-2.0 "C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, msys

I'm trying to use MSYS to create the MinGW SDL libraries from the latest SDL 2.0 Mercurial repository. (As of this posting.) I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.pantokrator.net/2006/08/08/setting-up-msysmingw-build-system-for-compiling-sdlopengl-applications/), and when I need to configure using MSYS I enter

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-stdio-redirect=no
```

into MSYS. It sputters out the following:

```
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I'm using gcc version 2.95 (According to "gcc -v"), the latest MSYS/MSYS-dtk, and the latest SDL 2.0 [Mercurial sources](http://hg.libsdl.org/). Does anyone know why MSYS might be giving me this error, or has anybody successfully built MinGW binaries from the current SDL 2.0 sources?

EDIT: Here's the config.log file generated by ./config:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-stdio-redirect=no

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = NFLODUDE
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.10(0.46/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.1
uname -v = 2004-03-15 07:17

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Python25/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2007)/Utilities/Bin/x86
PATH: /c/Perl/site/bin
PATH: /c/Perl/bin
PATH: /c/Windows/system32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Dell/Dell Wireless WLAN Card
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/OpenLibraries/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Trend Micro/AMSP
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin
PATH: /c/perl_op/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/gtk2/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/mlt/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/OpenLibraries/bin
PATH: /c/Windows/SysWOW64
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
PATH: .
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine
PATH: /c/Free Pascal Compiler/2.4.4/bin/i386-Win32
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/git/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/git/cmd
PATH: /c/PHP/
PATH: /c/PHP/ext
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/bin
PATH: /c/Users/Owner/Documents/Code Projects/Java Projects/LWJGL/lwjgl-2.8.3/native/windows
PATH: /c/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/TortoiseHg/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Bin
PATH: /c/Ruby193/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/g95/bin
PATH: /c/MinGW/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Nmap
PATH: /c/GNUstep/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2098: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
configure:2127: checking build system type
configure:2145: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2167: checking host system type
configure:2182: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2252: checking for gcc
configure:2268: found /c/Free Pascal Compiler/2.4.4/bin/i386-Win32/gcc
configure:2279: result: gcc
configure:2517: checking for C compiler version
configure:2524: gcc --version >&5
2.95
configure:2527: $? = 0
configure:2534: gcc -v >&5
Using builtin specs.
gcc version 2.95 19990728 (release)
configure:2537: $? = 0
configure:2544: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2547: $? = 1
configure:2570: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2597: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
Usage: cpp [switches] input output
Switches:
  -include <file>           Include the contents of <file> before other files
  -imacros <file>           Accept definition of marcos in <file>
  -iprefix <path>           Specify <path> as a prefix for next two options
  -iwithprefix <dir>        Add <dir> to the end of the system include paths
  -iwithprefixbefore <dir>  Add <dir> to the end of the main include paths
  -isystem <dir>            Add <dir> to the start of the system include paths
  -idirafter <dir>          Add <dir> to the end of the system include paths
  -I <dir>                  Add <dir> to the end of the main include paths
  -nostdinc                 Do not search the system include directories
  -nostdinc++               Do not search the system include directories for C++
  -o <file>                 Put output into <file>
  -pedantic                 Issue all warnings demanded by strict ANSI C
  -traditional              Follow K&R pre-processor behaviour
  -trigraphs                Support ANSI C trigraphs
  -lang-c                   Assume that the input sources are in C
  -lang-c89                 Assume that the input is C89; deprecated
  -lang-c++                 Assume that the input sources are in C++
  -lang-objc                Assume that the input sources are in ObjectiveC
  -lang-objc++              Assume that the input sources are in ObjectiveC++
  -lang-asm                 Assume that the input sources are in assembler
  -lang-chill               Assume that the input sources are in Chill
  -std=<std name>           Specify the conformance standard; one of:
                            gnu89, gnu9x, c89, c9x, iso9899:1990,
                            iso9899:199409, iso9899:199x
  -+                        Allow parsing of C++ style features
  -w                        Inhibit warning messages
  -Wtrigraphs               Warn if trigraphs are encountered
  -Wno-trigraphs            Do not warn about trigraphs
  -Wcomment{s}              Warn if one comment starts inside another
  -Wno-comment{s}           Do not warn about comments
  -Wtraditional             Warn if a macro argument is/would be turned into
                             a string if -traditional is specified
  -Wno-traditional          Do not warn about stringification
  -Wundef                   Warn if an undefined macro is used by #if
  -Wno-undef                Do not warn about testing undefined macros
  -Wimport                  Warn about the use of the #import directive
  -Wno-import               Do not warn about the use of #import
  -Werror                   Treat all warnings as errors
  -Wno-error                Do not treat warnings as errors
  -Wall                     Enable all preprocessor warnings
  -M                        Generate make dependencies
  -MM                       As -M, but ignore system header files
  -MD                       As -M, but put output in a .d file
  -MMD                      As -MD, but ignore system header files
  -MG                       Treat missing header file as generated files
  -g                        Include #define and #undef directives in the output
  -D<macro>                 Define a <macro> with string '1' as its value
  -D<macro>=<val>           Define a <macro> with <val> as its value
  -A<question> (<answer>)   Assert the <answer> to <question>
  -U<macro>                 Undefine <macro> 
  -u or -undef              Do not predefine any macros
  -v                        Display the version number
  -H                        Print the name of header files as they are used
  -C                        Do not discard comments
  -dM                       Display a list of macro definitions active at end
  -dD                       Preserve macro definitions in output
  -dN                       As -dD except that only the names are preserved
  -dI                       Include #include directives in the output
  -ifoutput                 Describe skipped code blocks in output 
  -P                        Do not generate #line directives
  -$                        Do not include '$' in identifiers
  -remap                    Remap file names when including files.
  -h or --help              Display this information
cpp: Too many arguments
configure:2600: $? = 1
configure:2638: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2645: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_set=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
ALSA_CFLAGS=''
ALSA_LIBS=''
AR=''
ARTSCONFIG=''
AS=''
BUILD_CFLAGS=''
BUILD_LDFLAGS=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DIRECTFBCONFIG=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED_FALSE=''
ENABLE_SHARED_TRUE=''
ENABLE_STATIC_FALSE=''
ENABLE_STATIC_TRUE=''
ESD_CFLAGS=''
ESD_CONFIG=''
ESD_LIBS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_CFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INCLUDE=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_AGE=''
LT_CURRENT=''
LT_RELEASE=''
LT_REVISION=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJECTS=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
POW_LIB=''
RANLIB=''
SDLMAIN_OBJECTS=''
SDL_BINARY_AGE='0'
SDL_CFLAGS=''
SDL_INTERFACE_AGE='0'
SDL_LIBS=''
SDL_MAJOR_VERSION='2'
SDL_MICRO_VERSION='0'
SDL_MINOR_VERSION='0'
SDL_RLD_FLAGS=''
SDL_STATIC_LIBS=''
SDL_VERSION='2.0.0'
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION_OBJECTS=''
WINDRES=''
XMKMF=''
X_CFLAGS=''
X_EXTRA_LIBS=''
X_LIBS=''
X_PRE_LIBS=''
ac_aux_dir='build-scripts'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-mingw32'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
lt_ECHO='echo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mingw'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

configure: exit 77
```

I really don't know what to make of config.log, though...

Comment: Can you upgrade? `gcc version 2.95` was released in 1999, so it's quite old (probably not related to your question though).

Comment: Did you had a look at the `config.log` file mentionned at the end of the error ? Can you post the content here ? You should also try to remove all whitespaces in your directory name like the first warning says.

Comment: Just added config.log, but I still don't see any evident weird errors...

Comment: Do you use AVG antivirus?  When I was trying to build SDL earlier today, AVG decided that the test programs created by `configure` were trojans, and began quarantining them.  `configure` then failed for me with the same error you're getting, until I replaced AVG with another antivirus program.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your `gcc` is not ready, needs some dependencies.

Long answer, troubleshooting guide:

Create a simple C file, like this:

```
main() {}
```

Try to run:

```
gcc simple.c
```

You should get the same message, about creating executables. Now make a verbose `gcc` call, adding `-v` switch. You should now know what is the command it cannot run. Maybe it is `as`? Maybe you need `binutils`? Maybe you need some library.